# Why parameter set in put method is not passed?

Tags: laravel, postman

Running activate method with sanctum id parameter I see that id parameter is not passed into activate control action.
In routes/api.php :

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group( function () {
    Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::resource('ads', AdController::class);
    Route::put('ads/{id}/activate', [AdController::class, 'activate']); 
});
```

In postman I pass parameter as http://server.com/api/ads/7/activate,
but problem is that in app/Http/Controllers/API/AdController.php :

```
public function activate(Request $request, Ad $ad)
{
    \Log::info(varDump($ad->id, ' -1 activate $ad->id::')); // this parameter is null - and error next :
    ...
} // public function activate(Ad $ad)
```

In Laravel Telescope I see details :

```
Request Details
Time    November 26th 2021, 5:08:08 PM (1:46m ago)
Hostname    master-laptop
Method  PUT
Controller Action   App\Http\Controllers\API\AdController@activate
Middleware  api, auth:sanctum
Path    /api/ads/7/activate
Status  500
Duration    113 ms
IP Address  127.0.0.1
Memory usage    2 MB
Tags    Auth:10
```

Why id parameter is wrong ?

```
    "laravel/framework": "^8.26.1",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.8",
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the name of the parameter in the method signature must match the route parameter name if you want implicit route model binding to happen

Comment: Did either of the below answer your question? If so, please could you mark one as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, to get [Implicit binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding) to work the uri segment in the route must match the parameter (variable) name of the method i.e.

Change `{id}` to `{ad}` so that it matches the `$ad` parameter of the `activate` method:

```
Route::put('ads/{ad}/activate', [AdController::class, 'activate']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use route binding you need to replace `{id}` to `{ad}`

```
Route::put('ads/{ad}/activate', [AdController::class, 'activate']);
```

If your issues is still not solved you can manually do it.
Add this code to `boot` method of `RouteServiceProvider`

```
Route::model('ad', Ad::class);
```